# How to increase efficiency of matrix operation in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix

I have a `N*N` upper triangular matrix with property such that, all its diagonal elements are `a1,a2,a3,...,aN`. I want that `a[i][j] (for all j>i)`
should be

```
(a[i][j-1] + a[i+1][j]) / 2.
```

I have many test cases, and I have to apply this property every time to calculate the answer. What is the most optimal way to do this, so that for all test cases the overall running time is less? Test cases: Inputs are `N and a1,a2,...,aN`.

To calculate the answer, I need to do:

```
a[0][0] + a[0][2] + ... + a[0][n-1] + a[2][n-1] + a[4][n-1] + ... + a[n-1][n-1].
```

My solution (which keeps getting timed out):

```
#include<stdio.h>
double a[2000][2000];
int main(){
int test;
scanf("%d",&test);
//int arr[2000];
while(test--){
    int n,i,j;
    //scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
         int num;
         scanf("%d",&num);
         if(n!=1)
            a[i][i] = num*0.5;
         else
            a[i][i] = num;
     }
    for(j=1;j<n;j++){
         int k=j;
         for(i=0;i<n-j;i++,k++){
             if(i==0 && k==n-1)
                 a[i][k] = (a[i+1][k]+a[i][k-1]);
             else
                 a[i][k] = (a[i+1][k]+a[i][k-1])*0.5;
         }
     }
     float sum=0.0;
     for(i=0;i<n;i+=2){
         if( i != n-1 )
         sum+=a[0][i]+a[n-1-i][n-1];
         else
         sum+=a[0][i];
     }
    printf("%.3f\n",sum);
}
getch();
}
```

Please provide some hints how to optimize the above code.

Comment: What have you got so far? Please show us some code.

Comment: one could easily see that the case corresponding to input n, is an extension of case corresponding to input n-1. The main problem is that I can't come up with a solution that makes use of this dependency (similar to DP in which we make use of previous values).

Comment: Maybe it should be here. http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to store the entire matrix.  You can determine the values of column j from column j-1, and replace the values as you go:

```
double b[2000];
double sum = 0;

for (j=0; j<n; ++j) {      
  b[j]=a[j];
  i=j;
  while (i>0) {
    --i;
    b[i] = (b[i+1]+b[i])*0.5;
  }
  if (i%2==1) sum += b[0];
}
for (i=2; i<n; i+=2) {
  sum += b[i];
}
```

This should make it more memory efficient and cache friendly, but it won't reduce the complexity.

You have some additional logic for when some values are multiplied by 0.5.  I'm not sure what that is based on.

Comment: The problem statement is that I need to get the expected score of person A in a game played against B. The game is governed by the following rule: There is a line of coins with known denominations. A player tosses a different coin and if heads turns up, he/she chooses the coin at the beginning of the line and if tails turns up, he/she chooses the coin at the end of the line. If A plays first, what is the expected value of A's score. a1, a2, a3, ... ,aN are the values of coins' denominations. Probability of getting a heads or a tails is 0.5.

Comment: @jigsawmnc: I don't see the relationship between the rules of the game and your calculations.

Comment: N's max value is 2000, hence the matrix a[2000][2000] is used. Suppose n = 3, then the game can be played in the following manner:(a1,a2,a3); (a1,a3,a2),(a3,a1,a2),(a3,a2,a1); where 1st and third term in every triplet represent, the possible coins A will pick. In this scenario, A's expected score will be (a1+a3)*0.5*0.5 + (a1+a2)*0.5*0.5 + (a3+a2)*0.5*0.5 + (a3+a1)*0.5*0.5...I have just tried to do the same calculation by using n*n matrix. 0.5*0.5 represent the overall probability: first coin is picked with probability of 0.5, second with 0.5 and third with 1 so total =0.5*0.5*1.

Comment: is there any other possible way of doing the same

Comment: @jigsawmnc: In your example, how is player B involved?

Comment: @jigsawmnc: Based on the problem statement, I would expect one possible game to go like this:  A tosses a coin and gets heads, so A chooses coin a1.  B tosses a coin and gets tails, so B chooses coin a3.  A tosses a coin and gets tails, so A chooses coin a2 (the only coin left).  A's score is then a1+a2.  Is that right?